# How do I turn off animations in latest Substance Ribbon bar?

Tags: java, swing, animation, substance

**Background:**

I'm working in a java swing client that uses Substance 5.1 with Flamingo 4.1 and am trying to upgrade to the most recent version of the newly maintained project Insubstantial 7.2.1

**Problem:**

It use to be that I could stop any and all animations (to gain CPU performance) by using this code:

```
UIManager.put(org.jvnet.lafwidget.LafWidget.ANIMATION_KIND,
                    org.jvnet.lafwidget.utils.LafConstants.AnimationKind.NONE);
```

However, in the latest version (and what seems like since version 6.0) there isn't an ANIMATION_KIND constant to use the the UIManager to stop the animations.  It seems like I could use the following code to for a stop for all the given animation kinds, but this dosn't work either:

```
AnimationConfigurationManager.getInstance().disallowAnimations(AnimationFacet.ARM);
AnimationConfigurationManager.getInstance().disallowAnimations(AnimationFacet.FOCUS);
AnimationConfigurationManager.getInstance().disallowAnimations(AnimationFacet.FOCUS_LOOP_ANIMATION);
AnimationConfigurationManager.getInstance().disallowAnimations(AnimationFacet.GHOSTING_BUTTON_PRESS);
AnimationConfigurationManager.getInstance().disallowAnimations(AnimationFacet.GHOSTING_ICON_ROLLOVER);
AnimationConfigurationManager.getInstance().disallowAnimations(AnimationFacet.ICON_GLOW);
AnimationConfigurationManager.getInstance().disallowAnimations(AnimationFacet.PRESS);
AnimationConfigurationManager.getInstance().disallowAnimations(AnimationFacet.ROLLOVER);
AnimationConfigurationManager.getInstance().disallowAnimations(AnimationFacet.SELECTION);
```

I've also tried the class specific signatures of these methods with the same result.

The documentation in Kirill's old [blog about Substance](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2007/11/29/substance-animation-primer.html) says there is a way to use a properties file as well, but there is no example given on what this should contain in either the blog or the documentation.

**Question:**

How do I stop all animations in the latest version of Insubstantial 7.2.1?